"Contentediable" the old node is preserved when rendering new ones (Vue 3)
Input data:
{
  parts: [
    {
      id: "part-1",
      type: "part",
      items: [
        {
          type: "content",
          tag: "b",
          content: "Hello",
        },
        {
          type: "content",
          tag: "br",
        },
        {
          type: "content",
          tag: "b",
          content: "World!",
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}

From this json we drove several times using the type="part". As you enter, they change json and react to its changes. Code available in sandbox. This approach is fine when working with normal input. But if you press Enter, then a new node is created, and for some reason, when re-rendering according to the list, when saving from the input data, the old text node remains, and so on ad infinitum. I would be very grateful for a detailed answer and solution to this problem.
If you add a unique key to each “part”, for example using crypto.randomUUID(), then with each input all “parts” are re-rendered and focus is lost. The same thing happens if you cause re-rendering of elements in other ways.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key

@MichalLevý wrote about keys, focus is lost.

Are you assigning UUID to the data or generating it on each render (:key="crypto.randomUUID()") ? If you doing the later (as it seems), you doing it wrong. Key should be be unique and stable

@MichalLevý I also considered the option where each entity would have :key and id in the input data. This method did not give anything and did not change behavior. For example, each object had its own unique identifier of type "content-1-1-2", which was mixed with the parent identifier for the key and got something like "block-1-content-2-2", and this is the same nothing changed.
